# Bash Script: For-Loop Over Newline... Syntax Explained?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

A frequently asked question both on SO and elsewhere is how to use a bash for-loop to go over each line of output. I'm aware of the answer, and I've been happily using the following for years now:

```
IFS=$'\n'
```

However, I'm slightly perplexed by the syntax used. I've had a good search / Google, but due to the sheer number of symbols which are used / ignored by search engines in the above - I've not found an explanation.

I've also recently spotted this in some output from another script. I was having problems echoing the result from netcat. Upon closer inspection, it turns out that the output from nc was in a similar format:

```
$'Some_Output_Here\r`
```

I ended up needing to cut off the `\r`, but wasn't sure of the best way to go about it, I ended up using `egrep -o ([0-9|a-Z]*)`. Any better ideas?

Comment: FYI, the preferred way to loop over a file's contents isn't with a for loop but a while read loop; see [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bash manual explains this quoting method, which it calls [ANSI-C Quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting).

Comment: The actual bash man page does not refer to the construct by that name (unfortunately), but you can find the relevant section by searching for "ANSI C".

Comment: The info Bash manual is more complete and understandable than the man page. Get it by running `info bash`, assuming it is installed.

Answer (score 1):

After Michael has edited the original post I think it makes more sense.

I think the person who posted needs to look up removal of carriage returns.
which should be sufficient with

```
sed -e 's/^M//g'
```

There are lots of other ways of removing control non printable characters:

All control characters:

```
egrep -v "[[:cntrl:]]"
sed -r "s/[[:cntrl:]]//g"
```

non printable characters

```
tr -dc '[:print:]'
```

Comment: All I did was remove "Any help / pointers would be greatly appreciated. jwa"